# difference between Alien-ffmpeg and ffmpeg

Tags: perl, ffmpeg

I want to record a video with perl i found the following 2 modules on cpan :

Alien-ffmpeg (https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GETTY/Alien-ffmpeg-0.103/lib/Alien/ffmpeg.pm ) and ffmpeg https://metacpan.org/pod/FFmpeg

what is the difference between those 2 modules , i see the Alien module don't have a documentaiton but its more up to date than ffmpeg module , how can i use it ?

are there also other recommeneded perl modules how to record mp4 file with Perl?

Answer (score 2):

[Alien](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien) modules are designed to ensure that you have the library available, either already installed in the system or by installing it within Perl's library paths itself. It does not provide an interface to use the library, another module would have to be written to provide this Perl interface, but it doesn't look like anyone has done so on CPAN. The `FFmpeg` module provides a Perl interface, but without using the Alien module so it requires the library to already be installed. It's also extremely old as you noted and [doesn't seem to be installable anymore](https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=FFmpeg). An alternative might be [FFmpeg::Command](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFmpeg::Command) which is not a Perl interface to the library but a wrapper for running the external command that must be installed separately. However I am not sure if FFmpeg is the best solution for recording your screen or an input device from Perl.

Comment: what you recommend for recording videos using perl script?